# break in a if else loop with a counter C#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a logic like below and i have a counter

```
if(condition1 == true)
{
           // do something

    if (counter==1)
    { 
        // break and go to last else statement
    }


}

else if (condition2==true)
{ 
    if (counter == 2)
    { 
        // break and go to last else statement
    }

    // do something
}
else
{
    // do this
}
```

how do i use break in this logic ?
i tried putting goto tag for else but apparently it is not valid . and i want to avoid switch as there is too much logic.

counter will be 2 in second if else loop and if counter = 2 then first if and secong if else should execute if counter=3 then first if second if else third if else should execute ans so on –

Comment: Can you make your last else statement a method?

Comment: "else if (condition2==true)" can be rewritten as "else if (condition2)"

Comment: If you are using a counter could you not refactor the code to use a `while` loop?

Comment: There's a "do something" after the `break`, is that desired? How should it work?

Comment: Something in the code above is not quite right. Could you check? You have a closed brace after the first if that doesn't make sense

Comment: Please reformat your code, indent it properly and include the loop statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like

```
if (condition1 &&  ( counter != 1 || counter != 2 ||          .... counter!= n )
{
// do something
}
else if (condition2 && (counter != 2 || ..            || counter!= n )
{
// do something
}

and so on 
else
{
// do this
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note**: Question was changed, this answer is meanwhile incorrect!

You can change the `if/else if` to include the `counter`. Then you don't need a `break` or `goto`:

```
if (condition1 && counter != 1)
{
    // do something
}
else if (condition2 && counter != 2)
{
    // do something
}
else
{
    // do this
}
```

Comment: The second one won't behave right if all the conditions are false.

Comment: counter will be 2 in second if else loop and
if counter = 2 then first if  and secong if else should execute
if counter=3 then first if second if else third if else should execute ans so on

Comment: @Rawling: OP has edited the question meanwhile. I will have a look later.

Comment: ... Yeah, that kinda changes things :p

Comment: @АндрейПро: Have a look, edited my answer according to your edits.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that a `break` statement doesn't jump outside an `if` condition, your code could be 
refactored in a more simple way (just pretend that the closed brace after the first if it's only a typo)

```
if(condition1 ==true && counter != 1)
{
    do something
}
else if (condition2==true && counter != 2)
{ 
    do something
}
else
{
    do this 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that your algorithm could be entirely redesigned, but without more context that's impossible to know.

In the meantime, you can refactor your final else clause into a separate method. You don't actually need to use `break` (which isn't valid in an `if` statement anyway), with judicious use of `else`.

```
private void MyMethod()
{
    if(condition1)
    {
        // do something

        if (counter==1)
        { 
            MyOtherMethod();
        }        
    }    
    else if (condition2)
    { 
        if (counter == 2)
        { 
            MyOtherMethod();
        }
        else
        {
            // do something
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MyOtherMethod()
    }
}

private void MyOtherMethod()
{
    // Do what was in your final else clause.
}
```

Prior to your question edits that moved the `do something' in the first if clause to before the counter check, this would have worked too:

Assuming your various "do something" statements were different things:

```
if (condition1 && counter != 1)
{
    // Do something.
}
else if (condition2 && counter != 1)
{
    // Do something.
}
else
{
    // Do something else.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the logic in the last else block in a seperate function which you can call whenever / wherever you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Don't**. Using a `break` and `continue` in such a big loop adds complexity and clutters your logic.

If a loop is getting too big, use one or more well-named function calls within the loop instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
bool myCondition = false;

if(condition1 ==true)
{
    if (counter==1){myCondition = true;}

    // do something
}
else if (condition2==true)
{ 
    if (counter==1){myCondition = true;}

    // do something
}

// so on 

if(myCondition)
{
    // do this 
}
```